# Segue to new view don't get the back pointer to the old view

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, transition, segue

I'm trying to build a custom segue, but i can't seem to get the right transition. The transition i would like is the opposite transition of the modal segue with default transition. So the transition i want is where my view slides down to show the new view. My code for my custom segue is posted below.

```
@implementation customSegue

//still need to find the right transition (from top to bottom)
- (void) perform 
{

UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

[UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{
                    [src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];
                }
                completion:NULL];

} 
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A navigation controller doesn't have a view of it's own -- it's view is that of the current view controller. Try using `src.view` in place of `src.navigationController.view`.